# NSNotificationCenter and UITabBar app

Tags: iphone, uitabbar, nsnotificationcenter

Here's my problem:

I have an app. It's based on four UITabBar views. On view 3 something happens and notification is being sent to NSNotificationCenter. There's an observer in view 1, which waits for said notification to first load some data from a local file (which were saved to the file before posting the notification) and then update a UITableView -> [TableView reloaddata]. So... i added nslogs to the observer and notification and they fire, but the UITableView is not updated when i switch to view 1 (when i restart the app, all is fine).

What can go wrong?

Btw. updating of view 1 is supposed to happen while view 3 is currently present.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put a `[tableView reloadData]` into your `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method of the ViewController.

Comment: Hi Sasha! Thanks for your answer. I moved the code from the observer to '-(void)viewDidAppear:(bool)animated', but unfortunately this strangely doesn't work too :-/ An NSLog says the method fires, but my table view doesn't reload. I can't fugure out why?

Comment: Perhaps check that you are addressing the correct tableView. One idea is to give each tableView a distinct name (according to in which tab it is).

Comment: All my table views have distinct names :-( I did more research though and the problem seems to be related to some delay with writing data to file on view 3. Is there any way to force writing data? I'm writing contents of NSArray on view 3 which is supposed to be loaded on view 1 but the data don't seem to save until the app is closed.

Comment: I've fixed it by destroying the data object and then craeting it again populated with fresh data on view 1. Thanks for your help, Sascha!